# TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete' how can i solve this

Tags: python, django

Python 3.8.1 django version 3.0.3
when i am run this code i am getting this error
**TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete'**

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

class UserProfileInfo(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    #additional
    profile_site = models.URLField(blank = True)

    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'profile_pics', blank = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from basic_app.models import UserProfileInfo

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget = forms.PasswordInput())

    class meta():
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password')

class UserProfileInfo(forms.ModelForm):
    class meta():
        model = UserProfileInfo
        fields = ('profile_site', 'profile_pic')
```

Comment: Can you add backtrace?

Answer (score 1):

You add a value for the [**`on_delete=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete) of the `OneToOneField`. This specifies what to do when the target object, here a `User` is removed. For example, we can specify a `CASCADE`:

```
class UserProfileInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_site = models.URLField(blank = True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Please read the documentation to decide what trigger you want to use.

Comment: it's show me ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: @Rasel: that is likely because you passed some `choices=` somewhere, where the items you passed was not a list of 2-tuples. But that is located somewhere else I think. Please ask a new question, and provide the *full* traceback.